# Why is the ring of matrices over a field simple?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Denote by $M_{n \times n}(k)$ the ring of $n$ by $n$ matrices with coefficients in the field $k$.  Then why does this ring not contain any two-sided ideal?

Thanks for any clarification, and this is an exercise from the notes of Commutative Algebra by Pete L Clark, of which I thought as simple but I cannot figure it out now.

Comment: Sorry for posting an elementary question, but I am really stuck.

Comment: Amusingly, a student in my course asked me about this exercise during a problem session.  My reply: "What?  That's not a *commutative* algebra question: how did that get in there?"  (And I didn't answer the question!)  It is, BTW, an extremely standard *non* commutative algebra question.  Any basic text which treats central simple algebras over a field should cover this.

Comment: @Pete: And any book on noncommutative rings, since it provides the standard example of an ideal that is prime but not completely prime.

Comment: @Pete Do you really need to look in a book on central simple algebras to find this fact? Actually, this is one of the first theorems I learnt after the definition of an "ideal".

Comment: @Amitesh: no, you don't.  (I don't think I said you did...) In fact, now that I am currently teaching a course on noncommutative algebra, you can look in my own lecture notes, to be made available shortly. :)  But to be clear, this is a completely elementary and not very difficult exercise, yes.

Comment: A very belated comment: as mentioned above, the classification of two-sided ideals of $M_n(R)$ appears as Theorem 22 in $\S$ 1.10 of my noncommutative algebra notes: http://math.uga.edu/~pete/noncommutativealgebra.pdf.  The statement and proof are virtually identical to the excerpt from Grillet's book in Leon Lampret's answer (notwithstanding the fact that I don't own Grillet's book, i.e., this is indeed a very standard result).

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: Thanks for telling me. Also, I shall apologize for the delay of the reply. Thanks again for your aureate comment.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Suppose that you have an ideal $\mathfrak{I}$ which contains a matrix with a nonzero entry $a_{ij}$. Multiplying by the matrix that has $0$'s everywhere except a $1$ in entry $(i,i)$, kill all rows except the $i$th row; multiplying by a suitable matrices on the right, kill all columns except the $j$th column; now you have a matrix, necessarily in  $\mathfrak{I}$, which contains exactly one nonzero entry, namely $a_{ij}$ in position $(i,j)$.

Now show that $\mathfrak{I}$ must contain *all* matrices in $M_{n\times n}(k)$. This will show that a $2$-sided ideal consists either of *only* the $0$ matrix, or must be equal to the entire ring.

*Added.* Now that you have a matrix that has a single nonzero entry, can you get a matrix that has a single nonzero entry on whatever coordinate you specify, and such that this nonzero entry is whatever element of $k$ you want, by multiplying this matrix (on either left, or right, or both) by suitable elementary matrices? Will they all be in $\mathfrak{I}$?

And...

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right) + \cdots$$

Comment: Well, @Arturo Magidin, the last paragraph is why I cannot get it, i.e. why does this imply that $\mathfrak{I}$ must contain *all* matrices in $M_{n*n}$? Can you be more specific, please, thanks in any case.

Comment: I got it!! Thanks very much, it clarified all the things such that I feel I was a dumb! In any case, thanks very much.

Comment: @awllower: Well, to make you feel better, prove the following generalization: if $R$ is a commutative ring with identity, then the ideals of $M_{n\times n}(R)$ are exactly the subrings of the form $M_{n\times n}(\mathfrak{I})$, where $\mathfrak{I}$ is an ideal of $R$.

Comment: It reminds me that the *basic number theory* by **Andre Weil** has contained this, doesn't it? BTW I do feel better now ^^, thanks.

Comment: @awllower: I'm not in my office, so I can't check. Sorry.

Answer (score 47):

A faster, and more general result, which Arturo hinted at, is obtained via following proposition from Grillet's *Abstract Algebra*, section "Semisimple Rings and Modules", page 360:

[image]

**Consequence:** if $R:=D$ is a division ring, then $M_n(D)$ is simple.

**Proof:** Suppose there existed an ideal of $M_n(D)$. By the proposition, it'd be of the form $M_n(I)$, for $I\unlhd D$, but division rings do not have any ideals (other than $0$ and $D$), so this is a contradiction. $\blacksquare$

Comment: So if $R$ is a simple ring, then so too is $M_n(R)$, right?

Comment: @goblin That's right. But for more specific results about simple rings, see Wedderburn's theorem and Thm.11.3.8, p.368 in Grillet.