# $M_n(D)$ has only finitely many right ideals if and only if $n = 1$ or $D$ is finite.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

> Let $D$ be a division ring. Then prove that $R = M_n(D)$ has only finitely many right ideals if and only if  $n = 1$ or $D$ is finite.

I know that the ideals of $M_n(D)$ are of the form $M_n(I)$, where $I$ is an ideal of $D$. So there are only $2$ possible choices which are $0$ or $M_n(D)$ since $D$ has only $0$ and $D$ as ideals. So how come the condition of $n = 1$ or $D$ is finite take place?

Comment: Dear gda, You are confusing ideals and right ideals.  Regards,

Comment: See lecture in abstract algebra,Vol II linear algebra by N.Jacobson page 232.

Comment: @YACP: I agree with you, but I think your comment is a little harsh.  @ gda: If you find an answer helpful, upvote it or accept that answer by clicking the check on the left hand side. This gives a small reward to the answerer who spent the time trying to help you, and encourages users to answer your questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty obvious that if $n=1$ or $D$ is finite, then $M_n(D)$ has only finitely many right ideals.

For the other direction I assume $n=2$ and leave the generalisation to the reader, the proof is a bit like proving there are infinitely many $1$-dimensional subspaces of the plane.

The first step is to see that
$$M_2(D)=\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&0\end{pmatrix}|a,b\in D\}\oplus \{\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\c&d\end{pmatrix}|c,d\in D\},$$
where the two summands are right ideals not containing any non-trivial proper right ideals (i.e. they are simple).

Now one can think of this as $S^2$ and try to find right ideals, like one tries to find lines in the plane.

I claim that $I(\lambda):=\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\\lambda a&\lambda b\end{pmatrix}|a,b\in D\}$ is a right ideal. Indeed:
$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\\lambda a&\lambda b\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\\gamma&\delta\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a\alpha+b\gamma &a\beta+b\delta\\\lambda(a\alpha+b\gamma) &\lambda(a\beta+b\delta)\end{pmatrix}$$
Now these are infinitely many right ideals if $D$ is infinite (This has to be checked, but this is a direct computation assuming there is an element in both).

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26726/what-are-the-left-and-right-ideals-of-matrix-ring-how-about-the-two-sided-ideal) is the reason for saying that "the proof is a bit like proving there are infinitely many $1$-dimensional subspaces of the plane."