# How to prove $f$ is in the span of $f_{1,\cdots, n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Suppose $f, f_{1,\cdots,n}\in X^*$ where $X$ is a normed vector space. How to show that, if $\cap Ker f_i \subset Ker f$, then $f$ is a linear combination of $f_{1,\cdots,n}$?

I'm at a loss even for the classical linear algebra cases (where $X$ is a finite dimensional Euclidean spade with $\ell^2$ norm, so really don't know how to proceed for the more general cases.

---

**EDIT**  It seems I might want to relax the conditions a little here. So let's now assume $X$ is a Banach space.

---

**EDIT** The Banach space assumption can be dropped. Any normed vector space is okay.

Comment: What is the ground field? $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: It may be helpful to consider $g: X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^n$ defined by $g(x) = (f_1(x), \ldots , f_n(x))$. Then $Ker g = \cap Ker f_i$.

Comment: @i707107 unspecified. Either the complexes or the reals.

Comment: I wonder if $X$ has to be just normed vector space. It would have been easier if it is Banach space.

Comment: @i707107 I'd like to see your insights. Thanks.

Comment: @Vim Your edit is useless, you do not need that $X$ be a Banach space, see user251257's proof you've chosen as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that we can reduce the problem to a finite dimensional $X$ by dividing out the closed subspace $K=\bigcap_{i=1}^n \ker f_i$.

Let $\mathbb F$ be the field of real or complex numbers.

1. Let $\bar f_1, \dotsc, \bar f_n, \bar f : X/K \to \mathbb C$ denote $f_1, \dotsc, f_n, f$ modulo $K$, that is
   $$ \bar f_i(x+K) = f_i(x) $$
   for every $x\in X$ and so on.
   The linear map $g:X/K \to \mathbb F^n$ defined by $g_i = \bar f_i$ has trivial null space and hence is injective.
   Thus, $X/K$ must be finite dimensional.
   Assume there is $\alpha\in \mathbb F^n$ with
   $$ \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \bar f_i = \bar f. $$
   Then, for the same $\alpha$ we have
   $$ \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i f_i = f. $$
2. Now the proof for the finite dimensional case:

   Let $F = span\{ f_1, \dotsc, f_n \}$. Then, $F$ is closed. Assume the converse, that is $f\notin F$. By hahn banach separation theorem there is a $\lambda\in X^{**}$ (isomorph to $X$) such that
   $$ Re\lambda(f) < \inf_{\alpha\in\mathbb F^n} Re\lambda\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i f_i \right) = \inf_{\alpha\in\mathbb F^n} \sum_{i=1}^n Re(\alpha_i \lambda(f_i)). $$
   That implies $\lambda(f_i) = 0$ for every $i$ (otherwise consider $\alpha_{i,n} = -n\overline{\lambda(f_i)}$).
   That is
   $$ \lambda\in \bigcap_{i=1}^n \ker f_i \subseteq \ker f. $$
   Clearly a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks. But two things I don't understand: 1). How is it implied that $\langle \lambda,f_i\rangle=0$, and 2). What's the contradiction here? I guess we have to create a $\lambda\in Ker f$ but not in $\cap Ker f_i$.

Comment: @Vim: 1.) If say $\langle \lambda, f_1 \rangle > 0$ consider $\alpha_1 \to -\infty$. 2.) we have $0 = \langle \lambda, f \rangle < \inf_{\alpha} \sum_i \alpha_i 0 = 0$.

Comment: thanks. Another follow up one: what version of Hahn Banach were you using here? I can't identify it with those I learned.

Comment: Ok. I now fully understand your proof and see the reason why you require the space be real and self-reflexive. However, since it is more natural to require a space to be Banach than to be self-reflexive etc., would you offer any insights into the Banach space case, if you please?

Comment: I guess your $g$ is a vector valued functional?

Comment: never mind let me take some time to digest it.

Comment: @user251257 In fact, there is no need of topology. The statement holds (exactly with your proof) for any vector space (finite or infinite dimensional and over any field $k$) with a separation of $f$ and $F$ by a hyperplane and replacing "inf" by "for all $\alpha\in k^n$".

Comment: @user251257 Of course not, but you first factor, as you did, by the intersection of the kernels.

Comment: Given $X$ isomorphic to its double dual, how do you relate $\lambda(f_i)$ with $f_i(\lambda)$? (What if $X$ isn't a Hilbert space)

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. does the separation theorem hold for any vector spaces? I guess at least the underlying field must be "dense" ($\Bbb C$ or $\Bbb R$) and there might be something else required.

Comment: @Vim It does in every finite dimensional space, this is the situation reached after factoring by the intersection of kernels (see user251257's proof replacing $\mathbb{C}$ by $k$).

Comment: @user251257 doesn't seem to be a problem. Just replace $\lambda$ with $\Re \lambda$?

Comment: Also I just got another proof. I've added it as an answer.

Comment: @Vim I fixed it.

Answer (score 7):

Another proof by my teacher: define $E=\{(f_1(x),\cdots,f_n(x)), x\in X\}$, a subspace of $K^n$ ($K$ denotes the real or complex field), and define $g:E\to K$ as $g(f_1(x),\cdots,f_n(x)):=f(x)$ (well defined by the kernel inclusion). Now we can extend $g$ to $g':K^n\to K$ since $E$ being a finite dimensional subspace is closed, and then 
$$f(x)=g(f_1(x)e_1+\cdots+f_n(x)e_n)=g'(f_1(x)e_1+\cdots+f_n(x)e_n)=\sum f_i(x)g'(e_i).$$

Comment: Wow. Nice :D ${}$

Comment: Nice abs elegant. You can replace easily [since $E$ being a finite dimensional subspace is closed] by [since $K^n$ is finite dimensional]. +1 !

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. thanks. I emphasised the closedness in order to hint at the application of Hahn Banach extension theorem, for what it's worth.

Comment: @Vim OK, I got the point.

Comment: I knew the solution should be something along this line. Here's another seemingly different problem that uses the same argument: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586280/any-left-ideal-of-m-n-mathbbf-is-principal