# Set of matrices with some properties

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Let there be a set $$ \mathscr M⊆\mathbf M_3^\Bbb C,\mathscr M≠∅ $$
with the following properties
$$A,B∈ \mathscr M\Longrightarrow A+B∈ \mathscr M $$
$$ A∈\mathscr M,C∈M_3^\Bbb C\Longrightarrow CA∈\mathscr M $$
$$ X∈M_{3,1}^\Bbb C,AX=O,\forall A∈\mathscr M \Longrightarrow X=0.$$
Prove that
 $$ \mathscr M=\mathbf M_3^\Bbb C.$$

Comment: What does $M_{3,1}^\Bbb C$ denote? And is $M_3^\Bbb C$ the set of $3\times 3$ matrices?

Comment: @ArnaudD. $\mathbf M_{3,1}^\Bbb C$ represents the set of matrices with 3 lines and 1 column. For the second question, yes, it represents the set of 3x3 matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E_{i,j}$ be a matrix consisting of all zeroes except for a $1$ on the $i$-th row and the $j$-th column. This matrix has the property that for another matrix $M$ the product $E_{i,j}M$ has all zeroes except for the $i$-th row of $M$ that shows up at the $j$ -th row. From this we conclude that the matrices of $\mathscr M $ are of the form $\begin{pmatrix}u_1 & u_2 & u_3\\v_1 & v_2 & v_3\\ w_1 & w_2 & w_3 \end{pmatrix}$ where $(u_1,u_2,u_3), (v_1,v_2,v_3), (w_1,w_2,w_3)$ are rows in a subspace $W $ of $\mathbf M_{1,3}^\Bbb C$, the set of $1 \times 3$ matrices. If $W$ has dimension $3$ we're done. If not then there exists a non-zero column $X = \begin{pmatrix}z_1 \\ z_2 \\ z_3 \end{pmatrix}$ such that $AX = 0$  $ \forall A \in \mathscr M $, but this is in contradiction with the last property.

Comment: Can you please adapt your solution without using vectors. Im a first year university student and i havent learned them yet.i have understood everything till the line you used "W".

Comment: In addition , why do you take only the fundamental matrices out of the whole set of matrices with complex elements?

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly. The funcamental matrices are used to filter out elements of $\mathscr M$ that consist of all zeroes except for one row. You can even switch rows from place, showing that all the rows belong to the same subspace of rows. Play a bit around with concrete examples and you will see what happens.

Comment: I apologise for bothering you with some many(probably juvenile)questions,but i was wondering why am i given the first property and ,secondly, i wanted to ask if u1,u2,u3 represent the coefficients of i,j,k in the group pf quaternions without real part.

Comment: No problem. Nothing to do with quaternions, they're just arbitrary complex numbers. I could have written $(m_{1,1}, m_{1,2},m_{1,3})$ and $(m_{2,1}, m_{2,2},m_{2,3})$ etc. but I was a bit lazy.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M_3(\mathbb{C})$ be the set of $3 \times 3$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$. Note that your first two conditions on $M$ together with $M \neq \emptyset$ are telling you that $M$ is a left ideal in $M_3(\mathbb{C})$. Such ideals can be described, see for example [What are the left and right ideals of matrix ring? How about the two sided ideals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26726/what-are-the-left-and-right-ideals-of-matrix-ring-how-about-the-two-sided-ideal). Now combine this with your last condition on $M$ to finish the proof.