# Proof concerning matrix composition.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

I have a statement which I don't know how to prove. All matrices are real, $n \times n$.

For all $0 < k < n$ the following has to hold.

It is impossible do define a matrix $A$ **of rank $\mathbf{k}$** such that the following holds.

$\forall M_1, M_2. A M_1 M_2 = A M_1 A M_2 $

Any hints greatly appreciated.

In case this is (as I suspect) part of a larger body of work which I am not aware of, I would appreciate if you gave me a pointer.

---

In case my statement is false, I would like a characterization of admissible $A$s
given $k$.

Comment: This is false. Take $A$ to be the zero matrix.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Sorry, I forgot the corner case. I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If $A$ is a such matrix then $A=0$:**
**Proof:** Lat $A$ such that $AM_1M_2=AM_1AM_2$ for all $M_1,M_2$:
In particular (for $M_1=M_2=I_n$) we obtain $A=A^2$, hence the polynomial $X^2-X=X(X-1)$ is annihilator of $A$, and it follow that $A$ is diagonalizable.
we denote $D=\text{diag}(\lambda_1\ldots,\lambda_n)$, then $A=P^{-1}DP$ for some invertible matrix $P$ and $\lambda_i$ the eigenvalues of $A$ , it is clear that $\lambda_i\in \{0,1\}$ for all $i$. In the equation we can omit $M_2$ (by $M_2=I_n$), now we obtain $AM=AMA$ for all $M$, so $P^{-1}DPM=P^{-1}DPMP^{-1}DP$  for all $M$.
also $D(PMP^{-1})=D(PMP^{-1})D$ for all $M$.
We know that the map $M\mapsto P^{-1}MP$ is bijective: now we obtain that 
$DM=DMD$ for all $M$. If we denote $M=(a_{i,j})$, the last equation is equivalent to 
$\lambda_ia_{i,j}=\lambda_i\lambda_ja_{i,j}$ that is $\lambda_ia_{i,j}(1-\lambda_j)=0$, since $D$ is not invertible ($A$ is not invertible $\text{rank}(A)<n$ ) there is $j_0$ such that $\lambda_{j_0}=0$, by taking $a_{i,j}=1$ for all $i,j$ we obtain $\lambda_i(1-\lambda_{j_0})=0$ for all $i$ , that is $\lambda_i=0$ for all $i$, Then $D=0$, it follow that $A=0$.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\M}[0]{\mathcal M}$Let $\M$ be the algebra of $n \times n$ matrices, and consider the map
$$
f : \M \to \M, \qquad f(M) = AM.
$$
The hypothesis implies that $f$ is a homomorphism of algebras.

Now [$\M$ is a simple ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22629/why-is-the-ring-of-matrices-over-a-field-simple), so that by considering $\ker(f)$ we see that

- either $\ker(f) = \M$, so that $f$ is the zero map - this can only happen of course when $A = 0$, a case that has been excluded,
- or $\ker(f) = \{ 0 \}$, so that $f$ is injective, and thus an isomorphism - this is because $f$ is also a linear map - it follows that $A$ is invertible (there must be $M$ such that $AM = f(M) = I$, the identity matrix), again a case that has been excluded.

In the case when $A$ has rank $n$, we see immediately that we must have $A = I$.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative answer, in the spirit of that of Hamou.

Setting $M_{1} = M_{2} = I$, we see that $A = A^{2}$, and thus we may assume
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
&1\\
&&\ddots\\
&&&1\\
&&&&0\\
&&&&&\ddots\\
&&&&&&0
\end{bmatrix},\tag{diag}
$$
where there are $k$ ones, with $0 < k < n$ ones, and omitted entries are zero.

> *Addendum* This is because $A$ is a root of $x^{2} - x$. Since $A \ne 0, I$, we have that $x^{2} -x$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$. Since $x^{2} -x$ has the distinct roots $0$ and $1$, $A$ can be put in diagonal form with $0$ and $1$ on the main diagonal, that is, there is an invertible matrix $P$ such that the conjugate $P^{-1} A P$ of $A$ by $P$ has the form (diag). Clearly, conjugating the main identity
>   $$
> A M_{1} M_{2} = A M_{1} A M_{2}
> $$
>   by $P$ we find that the matrix (diag) still satisfies the main identity, as claimed.

Now choose $M_{2} = I$, and $M_{1} = e_{1n}$, the matrix whose only non-zero entry is a $1$ in the $(1, n)$ position.

Then $AM_{1} = M_{1} \ne 0 = A M_{1} A$, a contradiction

Comment: How do you get from $A$ being idempotent to $A$ having the particular form you gave? I understand you can do this via the diagonalization argument provided by Hamou, but your answer may be read to suggest there is some magic step I'm unaware of where you can do this immediately. @AndreasCaranti.

Comment: @ziutek, I have added the explanation you required - no magic ;-) but rather a standard fact on idempotent matrices, based on minimal polynomials.