# Working with ideals and proving that S in not an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

[image]

For this question, How do I show that the only 2 sided ideals are 0 and R? I understand the theory behind ideals but I have a very theoretical understanding and I was hoping someone could help solve this question?

From my understanding, $ P(x) = C0 + C1X + ... + CkX^k $ and I said $ Q[x] $ could be polynomails in the variable X with coefficinets in Q.

For $ b) $ I know I need to find a P(x) where 
$\begin{bmatrix}
P(0) & 0 \\
P'(0)& P(0) \\
\end{bmatrix}$

is equal to 
$\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 \\
b & a \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$

For $c)$ I need a P(x)=x. p(0)=0 and P'(x)=1. How would I go about doing this, Ive been working on it for a few days and thats all I have so far so any help would be apprecaited!

Comment: The question about ideals of a matrix ring is answered on the site at least 5 times. You should search for that.

Comment: I found the general proof on the site but I was hoping for a less theoretical answer, I can solve the question using the answers on the site its more of an understanding for this case in particular that I am hoping for

Comment: A majority of the solutions are elementary rather than theoretical. Look again.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/22629/29335) for example. Also try the 10+ duplicates linked to it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint to 2: If $F$ is a surjective ring homomorphism, the kernel $I$ of $F$ is an ideal of ${\Bbb Q}[x]$ such that ${\Bbb Q}[x]/I$ is isomorphic to $S$. (Homomorphism theorem)

Hint to 3: From the quotient structure of $S$ it is clear that $S$ is not an integral domain. Moreover, the ideals of $S$ correspond exactly to the ideals of ${\Bbb Q}[x]$ containing $I=\langle x^2\rangle$. (First isomorphism theorem)