# Statement/proof that a matrix algebra cannot be *-isomorphic to the direct sum of smaller matrix algebras.

Tags: reference-request, c-star-algebras

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_p \in \mathbb{N}$ with all $k_i < n$.

I'm writing a proof that asserts $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ cannot be *-isomorphic to any subalgebra of $\mathcal{A}$ where $$\mathcal{A} = \mathfrak{gl}(k_1,\mathbb{C}) \oplus \mathfrak{gl}(k_2,\mathbb{C}) \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathfrak{gl}(k_p,\mathbb{C})$$

More specifically, I'm asserting that $\not\exists \;\mathcal{B}\subseteq \mathcal{A}, U$ such that $$U\mathcal{B}U^\dagger = \mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C}) \oplus 0_{m\times m}$$ where $U$ is a unitary matrix and $m = \sum_i k_i - n$.

To me, this result seems obvious based on the observation that the matrix blocks of $\mathcal{A}$ can never fully "cover" $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C})$. It's been suggested that I might find a proof of it (or something similar) in a book on Morita equivalence. My problem is that I know little about operator theory and even less about Morita equivalence. I'm simply in need of a reference (ideally, a book name and chapter/page number) to back up this assertion.

Of course, if my intuition is wrong and the assertion is false, please set me straight.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a reference for a proof, but a proof isn't too hard to obtain, as long as you know that [$M(n,\mathbb C)$ is simple](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22629/why-is-the-ring-of-matrices-over-a-field-simple):

We can proceed by induction on $p$.  If $p=1$, this is obvious just by counting dimensions.  Suppose the result holds for some $p$, and 
$$\mathcal A\cong M(k_1,\mathbb C)\oplus\cdots\oplus M(k_{p+1},\mathbb C),$$
with $k_i<n$ for $1\leq i\leq p+1$.  If $M(n,\mathbb C)\subset\mathcal A$, then $M(n,\mathbb C)\cap(0\oplus M(k_{p+1},\mathbb C))$ is an ideal in $M_n(\mathbb C)$, and since $k_{p+1}<n$ we must have $M(n,\mathbb C)\cap(0\oplus M(k_{p+1},\mathbb C))=0$.  It follows that 
$$M(n,\mathbb C)\subset M(k_1,\mathbb C)\oplus\cdots\oplus M(k_p,\mathbb C)\oplus 0,$$
which is impossible.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll see about maybe working this into an appendix if I'm unable to find a reference.