# Doubts: All ideals of $M_n(R)$ are of the form $M_n(I)$, where $I$ is an ideal of $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

I know the result is true, however, if we are to consider $E_{ij} = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & ... & 0\\
. & . & ...& . \\
0 & 0 & r_{ij} & 0 \\
. & . & ...& . \\ \end{pmatrix} : r_{ij}\in R  \right\}$. 
$E_{ij}$ is an ideal of $M_n(R)$ but doesn't appear to be of the type $M_n(I)$.

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What makes you think this is an ideal ?

Comment: Does this help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22629/why-is-the-ring-of-matrices-over-a-field-simple?

Comment: Well, if $P$ is a permutation matrix, then $P(r E_{ij})P^{-1}$ should lie on the "ideal". But for most $P$, this shuffles the columns so that the non-zero entry is no longer in the $(i,j)$ coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

Your set is not closed by multiplication on the right.

You can multiply a nonzero element like that by a matrix with a 1 in the $j,1$ position and zeros elsewhere, and that is not in your set.

Comment: Thanks this clears it up.