# Ideals of the ring of matrices over $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be the ring of matrices  $$R=\big\{\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix} |a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}\big\}$$

I want to find all the ideals of $R$. We know that $R$ has $16$ elements and therefore the possible orders of the non-trivial ideals are $2,4,8,16$. Besides taking all the possible cases for the elements of the matrices how can I approach this problem?

Comment: The ring $R=M_2(K)$ has only the trivial ideals, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22629/why-is-the-ring-of-matrices-over-a-field-simple?noredirect=1&lq=1). Here $K=\Bbb Z/2$ is a field.

Comment: It's true in general that the two-sided ideals of the ring of matrices over any field are $\{0\}$ and $R$.  For the left ideals, there is a bijective correspondece between the vector subspaces of a vector space and the left ideals of its ring of matrices, given by $W\mapsto \{A\in k^{n\times n}\,:\, \ker A\supseteq W\}$. Similarly, there is a bijective correspondence between the vector subspaces and the right ideals given by $W\mapsto \{A\in k^{n\times n}\,:\, \operatorname{col}A\subseteq W\}$.

Comment: For the right ideals, let $v_1,v_2$ be the two rows of $V$, then there are 5 cases for $V M_2$: $v_1K+v_2K=K^2$ and $ v_1=v_2=0$ and $v_1\ne 0,v_2=0$ and  $v_2\ne 0,v_1=0$ and  $v_1\ne 0,v_2 \in v_1 K^*$